# How to structure a huge mysql database with many profiles

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

The question is how to structure a huge mysql database with for example 10.000 profiles.

**Example1**

1 Database

3 Database fields (field_profile, field_images, field_posts etc.)

field_profile 10.000 profiles with an id and the rest of the information.

field_images 150.000 images related to the id in database_profile.

field_images 350.000 posts related to the id in database_profile.

Slow searching but when i want to change something really easy.

**Example2**

1 Database

30.000 Database fields (field_profile_profile1, field_images_profile1, field_posts_profile1, field_profile_profile2, field_images_profile2, field_posts_profile2 etc..

field_profile_profile1 1 profile with information.

field_images_profile1  50

field_posts_profile1 3500

Fast searching but when i want to change something really difficult?!

**Which example is the best or is there a better option?**

Comment: Could it be, that instead of "field" you mean "table"? Else it doesn't make much sense. However, Example 2 doesn't make much sense in both cases. And the numbers you provide are not "huge" ;)

Comment: I'm sorry i mean a table! Maybe in the future the numbers are milions so thats why i have to know.

Comment: 10k rows is not alot, index your keys and you should be fine

Comment: With "millions" you mean "1 Million"? When you come to "tenth or houndred millions", then you can consider changing the database, or maybe the schema, but till then, you have very much time to learn everything about database optimizations :)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for normalization, according that your number of records are not even close to huge:

```
[table_profile]
profile_id

[table_image]
image_id
profile_id

[table_post]
post_id
profile_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You should simply come up with table that if Field profile and field image is same for different post then

```
table profile  
field_id   field_profile   field_image 

table post
field_id   field_post
```

Second option if field_profile , field_image is different every time then come up with single table .

```
table field
field profile  field_image  field_post
```

Try to store repeating data in different table and use id's whenever needed , it will  decrease your data storage and increase speed of database access .